# the derivative of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Could someone help me to figure out this problem? I'd appreciate it!

This problem illustrates that the derivative of a diﬀerentiable function need not be diﬀerentiable.

Let $f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \frac{x^3}{|x|} & \text{if $x \neq 0$}\\ 0 & \text{if $x = 0$} \end{array} \right.$

**(a)** Show $f(x)$ is diﬀerentiable at $x$ and ﬁnd a formula (with justification of course) for $f'(x)$, for all $x \neq 0$.

**(b)** Show $f$ is diﬀerentiable at $0$ and ﬁnd $f'(0)$.

**(c)** Parts *(a)* and *(b)* show that $f'(x)$ is deﬁned on all of $\Bbb R$. Prove $f(x)$ is not diﬀerentiable at $0$.

Comment: And.... your effort being??

Comment: Maybe you should also add your first approach / thoughts on the problem, then people will be able / more willing to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

(a)
If $x>0$,
$$f(x)=x^2$$

Find its derivative, call it $g_1(x)$.

If $x<0$, $$f(x)=-x^2$$

Find its derivative, call it $g_2(x)$.

(b)
If $x = 0$, 
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{(h)^3}{|h|}}{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{h^2}{|h|}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}|h|$$

Find this quantity, call it $b$.

(c) Evaluate these limits

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{g_1(h)-b}{h}$$

and

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-}\frac{g_2(h)-b}{h}$$

These two numbers should not be equal.